# ios drop shadow for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to get a drop shadow under `UILabel`

Here is my code:

```
[lineBottom_btn3dot setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [lineBottom_btn3dot.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [lineBottom_btn3dot.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1.5f)];
    [lineBottom_btn3dot.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
    lineBottom_btn3dot.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    lineBottom_btn3dot.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
```

It show label , but it's not show drop shadow.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
[lineBottom_btn3dot setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[lineBottom_btn3dot setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give significantly large `Y` offset to your shadow, for example `10`.
Your code is correct but you can't notice it with a little value.
And also increasing `shadowRadius` looses the meaning of dropped shadow.
To test it you can change your code like below:

```
[lineBottom_btn3dot setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,10)];
lineBottom_btn3dot.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
```